# How to implement Search function and Add Comments in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

guys:

I use swagger to make api document. I use ASP.NET WebAPI2 to develop WebAPI.
And I met three questions:

First: How could I Add Comments for the WebAPI Controller? I try to add Comment on Controller

```
namespace IMCAPI.Controllers
{
/// <summary>
/// Value API
/// </summary>
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all Values
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

, but [not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYUa5.png).

Second:How could I search specific WebAPI in Swagger by brower Url? like this [Browser Url Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQsVa.png)

For example, if I want to search Value API, I input Value in the red section,I want the search result would just show Value API, I don't want other API appears(like Account). Or how to setting SwaggerConfig.cs that can have the search function?

Third:I want to know whether swagger could just read one xml file? I search the Internet, they demo like this

```
    private static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}/App_Data/IMCAPI.XML", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    }
```

If I have multiple XML file, how could I integrate in the swagger?

that it. Hope somebody can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is too broad, try editing it. Also share your code which shows your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question: The comments *are* appearing, you've put them on the `Get` method in your code, they're appearing on the `Get` method in your screenshot. If what you want is a description of the whole service, the [Swagger documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#additional-service-metadata) says to use the `Description` method.

Your second: You can't it shows all the methods on that API.

Third: The [Swagger documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#including-xml-comments) says you call `IncludeXmlComments` multiple times with the path to each XML.